# Публикация приложения в Google Play Market

Tags: android, google-play

Если я не укажу company domain при создании приложения и оставлю nan то пройдет ли оно в play market?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

company domain сам по себе не записывается в приложение. Он используется в помошьнике создания нового проекта, и используется для составления package id. Больше нигде он не используется. Просто укажите вручную package id, и все будет в порядке.